# Passive form of "change", which is right?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have an exercise. I have to choose one of these phrases:

> Water can change into ice.
>   Water can be changed into ice.

My question is which one is right?

Comment: Hello,  Can you give some more context.  What do you think and why.  Who are you saying this to? Why this phrase? Can you find any examples of the phrase on the internet? All this will help you get a useful answer.

Comment: sorry. there is no context. so i suppose both make sense?

Comment: What do you mean "no context"?  Literally this means  "There is no reason for me to say this."  There is always context.  Why are you asking about this phrase?  Can you find any examples?

Comment: I understand you. but it's just an exercise. only a sentence. without any other hints.

Comment: can you see my question? Water can change into ice.
Water can be changed into ice. which is right?

Comment: Ah, it's an exercise!  That is context. **Good**.  Now we are happy to help with your homework, but we expect some effort to be shown. Have you found any more examples? Can you say what you think the answer is, and why?

Comment: With much respect, before posting a question you might want to do some research, maybe it could be answered with a simple search on google.

Comment: previously i think both make sense. Because water can turn into ice automatically when temperature droped. So water can change into ice, I suppose, is right.  but even though sometimes the temperature didn't drop, and water exists in the form of fluid, peeple can make it become ice. so Water can be changed into ice is also right. I googled,and found a sentence which is Boiling water can turn into ice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are valid. The difference lies in the context.

```
"Water can change into ice" denotes the capability of water to change it's form.


"Water can be changed into ice" denotes the capability of a person or an object to change water's form.
```

The second statement would make more sense if additional information is given.
Eg. Water can be changed into ice by refrigerating it.